# Accessing Nested Children in Firebase Database Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

My current firebase database structure is like this

```
customer
  -L1x2AKUL_KNTKXyza
    name:"abc"
    subscription
      -L1x2AKlvmG0RXv4gL
        sub_no: "123"
        sub_name: ""
      -L1x2AKlvmG0RXv4ab
        sub_no: "456"
        sub_name" ""
  -L1x2AKUL_KNTKXymk
    name:"xyz"
    subscription
      -L1x2AKlvmG0RXv4xy
        sub_no: "789"
        sub_name: ""
```

I am trying to access all subcriptions of all customer records at once.

This is the code I am using:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "customer")

ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children

        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {

            let imageSnap = rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "subscription")
            let dict = imageSnap.value as! NSDictionary

            //self.vehicleListDict.append(dict.object(forKey: "sub_no") as! NSDictionary)

            print("value : \(dict)")

        }
        print("vehicleListDict : \(self.vehicleListDict)")
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I am unable to access all the subscriptions within all customer records at once. Its only accessing till one level. I tried to put a while loop within the while that exists but that also does not give me the output needed. It goes in an infinite loop instead. Please could anyone help. I am using firebase realtime database for the first time.

The fetched values should be

```
123
456
789
```

Comment: What you are requesting doesn't make sense.

Comment: I need a list of all subscriptions.. And they are stored with each customer's details.. so need to traverse it this way

Comment: These functions should be done I googles cloud functions.

Comment: This is easy to do. However, can you explain why you want that data (i.e. what is the use case - why do you want all of the subscriptions at one time for all customers) as it may require a re-tool of the Firebase structure to really get the data out that you want.

Comment: @Jay There is a drop down menu in which all subscriptions need to be shown. I cannot change the firebase structure. Will have to fetch from current structure itself. Can you please help.. I'm still struggling on this

Comment: What if there are 10,000 subscriptions? That would be a terrible experience for the user; trying to look through all of those for a single entry. On top of that, if they are all listed together, how would one know which subscription goes with which name? Going further, if there are 100k, 200k or even 1M subscriptions, that would overload the device and cause crashes.

Comment: Subscriptions won't be so many as app is going to be used by internal team only. Cannot change the structure of this DB. Please suggest some way to fetch this data in current scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for doing specifically what you are asking is

```
let customerRef = self.ref.child("customer")
customerRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let subscriptionSnap = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "subscription")
    for child in subscriptionSnap.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let subNo = dict["sub_no"] as! String
        print(subNo)
    }
})
```

and the output is

```
a123
a456
a789
```

*note that I am reading the sub_no as a STRING which is why I added 'a' in front. If they are actually integers change the line to

```
let subNo = dict["sub_no"] as! Integer
```

*note2 this will leave a .childAdded observer to the main node in question so any further children that are added will fire the code in the closure.

**Edit:**

If you want to just retrieve all of the data at one time and not leave a childAdded observer then this will do it:

```
let customerRef = self.ref.child("customer")
customerRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for customerChild in snapshot.children {
        let childSnap = customerChild as! DataSnapshot
        let subscriptionSnap = childSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "subscription")
        for subscriptionChild in subscriptionSnap.children {
            let snap = subscriptionChild as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let subNo = dict["sub_no"] as! String
            print(subNo)
        }   
    }
})
```

and the output is

```
a123
a456
a789
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jay! I have one more similar issue in fetching nested children. Could you initiate a chat for the same?

Comment: @Dia If it's a different question then post it as a question as we'll take look.